# How to convert Row Dataframe to Array Json Output with Spark Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have code to convert row dataframe but i have problem to output in array.

Input : file.txt

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------+
|id                             |var                 |score  |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------+
|12345                          |A                   |8      |
|12345                          |B                   |9      |
|12345                          |C                   |7      |
|12345                          |D                   |6      |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

output:

```
{"id":"12345","props":[{"var":"A","score":"8"},{"var":"B","score":"9"},{"var":"C","score":"7"},{"var":"D","score":"6"}]}
```

I tried using collect_lis not successfully. My code is with scala

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.read.json("file.txt")
val dfCol = df.select(
    df("id"),
    df("var"),
    df("score"))
dfCol.show(false)

val merge = udf { (var: String, score: Double) =>
      {
        var + "," + score     }
    }

val grouped = dfCol.groupBy(col("id"))
      .agg(collect_list(merge(col("var"),col("score")).alias("props"))
grouped.show(false)
```

My question is, how data row convert in output array json?

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you try group the DF by id and then write the DF to JSON file itself? i hope that should return as array of var and props.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, i have answer in my question.

```
            case class Props(var: String, score: Double)
            case class PropsArray(id: String, props: Seq[Props])
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
            val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

            val df = sqlContext.read.json("file.txt")
            val dfCol = df.select(
                df("id"),
                df("var"),
                df("score"))


            val merge = udf { (var: String, score: Double) =>
                  {
                    var + "," + score     }
                }

            val grouped = dfCol.groupBy(col("id"))
                  .agg(concat_ws("|", collect_list(merge(col("var"), col("score")))).alias("props"))

        val merging = grouped.map(x => {
              val list: ListBuffer[Props] = ListBuffer()
              val data = x.getAs[String]("props").split("\\|")

              data.foreach { x =>
                val arr = x.split(",")

                try {

                  list.+=:(Props(arr.apply(0).toString(),arr.apply(1).toDouble))

                } catch {
                  case t: Throwable => t.getMessage
                }

              }

              PropsArray(x.getAs("id"), list.toSeq)

            }).toDF()
```

you can run

```
merging.show(false)
```

and you must add library in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks.